# Does the Parappa the Rapper anime actually have any rapping?

Tags: parappa-the-rapper

I watched the Parappa the Rapper anime several years ago, given that it was one of my favorite video games. However, I quickly discovered a fatal flaw: there was no actual rapping!! The producers instead decided to make it a children's show. How do you make an anime about a rapping dog with no actual rapping?!

I only watched a few episodes before I dropped it. But if there actually is some rapping somewhere in the show, it would at least be worth my time to watch that. Does Parappa (or anyone else) rap at any point in the series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anime is about Parappa, not about rapping. So there's no really rapping, if I remember correctly.

Comment: To clarify, did you watch the whole series, or just a few episodes? I think you are probably correct (which is unfortunate), but in particular I'm looking for an answer from someone who has seen the whole series since I've seen the first 4 or 5 episodes myself and I know there was no rapping in those.

Comment: Same as you, I have only watched the first episodes. I quit after a friend, who watched the complete anime, told me that the anime isn't actually about rapping.

Comment: I've talked to a couple more people who claimed to have watched the full show and said there was no rapping. I think at this point there's enough anecdotal evidence to accept this answer for now, though I'd still like a definitive confirmation of this from someone who has watched the full series if possible.